# How to choose index to optimize this MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, query-performance, index, optimization, index-tuning

```
SELECT * FROM ehd_historical_data 
WHERE exchange = 'NYSE ARCA' AND symbol = 'ZROZ' AND blacklisted = 0 
ORDER BY high DESC LIMIT 1;

SELECT * FROM ehd_historical_data 
WHERE exchange = 'NYSE ARCA' AND symbol = 'ZROZ' AND blacklisted = 0 
  AND date < '2023-10-10' 
ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1;
```

These 2 are my typical queries. They are very fast and simple, but I execute such queries 10K+ times in a row, so together, they get slow.

I have these 2 index.

```
Index 1: ALTER TABLE `trading`.`ehd_historical_data` 
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`exchange`, `symbol`, `date`) USING BTREE;

Index 2: ALTER TABLE `trading`.`ehd_historical_data` 
ADD INDEX `exchange_symbol_blacklisted_date` (`exchange`, `symbol`,
  `blacklisted`, `date`) USING BTREE;
```

Some EXPLAIN results

```
EXPLAIN SELECT adjusted_close FROM ehd_historical_data USE INDEX(primary) 
WHERE exchange = 'NYSE ARCA' AND symbol = 'ZROZ' AND blacklisted = 0 
  AND date <= '2023-02-28' 
ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1;

{
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "cost_info": {
      "query_cost": "1313.07"
    },
    "ordering_operation": {
      "using_filesort": false,
      "table": {
        "table_name": "ehd_historical_data",
        "access_type": "range",
        "possible_keys": [
          "PRIMARY"
        ],
        "key": "PRIMARY",
        "used_key_parts": [
          "exchange",
          "symbol",
          "date"
        ],
        "key_length": "1026",
        "rows_examined_per_scan": 6440,
        "rows_produced_per_join": 644,
        "filtered": "10.00",
        "backward_index_scan": true,
        "cost_info": {
          "read_cost": "1248.67",
          "eval_cost": "64.40",
          "prefix_cost": "1313.07",
          "data_read_per_join": "724K"
        },
        "used_columns": [
          "exchange",
          "symbol",
          "date",
          "blacklisted",
          "adjusted_close"
        ],
        "attached_condition": "((`trading`.`ehd_historical_data`.`blacklisted` = 0) and (`trading`.`ehd_historical_data`.`symbol` = 'ZROZ') and (`trading`.`ehd_historical_data`.`exchange` = 'NYSE ARCA') and (`trading`.`ehd_historical_data`.`date` <= DATE'2023-02-28'))"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```
EXPLAIN SELECT adjusted_close FROM ehd_historical_data USE INDEX(exchange_symbol_blacklisted_date) 
WHERE exchange = 'NYSE ARCA' AND symbol = 'ZROZ' AND blacklisted = 0 
  AND date <= '2023-02-28' 
ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1;

{
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "cost_info": {
      "query_cost": "3547.75"
    },
    "ordering_operation": {
      "using_filesort": false,
      "table": {
        "table_name": "ehd_historical_data",
        "access_type": "range",
        "possible_keys": [
          "exchange_symbol_blacklisted_date"
        ],
        "key": "exchange_symbol_blacklisted_date",
        "used_key_parts": [
          "exchange",
          "symbol",
          "blacklisted",
          "date"
        ],
        "key_length": "1027",
        "rows_examined_per_scan": 3328,
        "rows_produced_per_join": 3328,
        "filtered": "100.00",
        "index_condition": "((`trading`.`ehd_historical_data`.`blacklisted` = 0) and (`trading`.`ehd_historical_data`.`symbol` = 'ZROZ') and (`trading`.`ehd_historical_data`.`exchange` = 'NYSE ARCA') and (`trading`.`ehd_historical_data`.`date` <= DATE'2023-02-28'))",
        "backward_index_scan": true,
        "cost_info": {
          "read_cost": "3214.95",
          "eval_cost": "332.80",
          "prefix_cost": "3547.75",
          "data_read_per_join": "3M"
        },
        "used_columns": [
          "exchange",
          "symbol",
          "date",
          "blacklisted",
          "adjusted_close"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**My questions are:**

1. Why second index which is more specific and cover all the WHERE clause is slower based on the "query_cost" output?
2. Is there any other index structure which is better suited for my use case?

Comment: "10K+ queries in a row" -- With the same values (ZROZ, etc)?  How big is the table?  How much RAM?  What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?

Comment: @RickJames It's different values each time. Table is 90M rows / 15 GB. RAM is 64 GB. innodb_buffer_pool_size is 4G

Comment: I augmented my Answer to recommend a bigger buffer_pool setting.

Answer (score 0):

In InnoDB, primary key lookups are generally more efficient than secondary key lookups. A secondary key lookup finds the primary key value, which is then used to look up the row. So it's kind of twice the lookup work. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-index-types.html

Secondary key lookups have more overhead than primary key lookups, but secondary keys are still very good for optimization.

You could avoid the second lookup if your query references only columns in the secondary index (making it a "covering index"). Since you used `SELECT *` that's probably not the case.

The difference might be insignificant. Did you run the query and find that it was slow? Or are you just making an assumption that it's slow based on the EXPLAIN report?

Comment: Thank you.

I used `SELECT *` to keep it simple in the example, but in general, I am selecting columns that are not part of any INDEX.

Yes. I am making performance assumption based on EXPLAIN report.

I have to optimize these SQL queries be fast even if there are 10K queries in a row. What should be the best strategy for me? Should I delete the `INDEX 2`? Should I also change anything in `INDEX 1` or maybe create a complete different index?

Comment: Use EXPLAIN as one indicator of performance, but not the end of the story. You also need to test executing the query as well, using a data set that is typical of your real-world data set (number of rows, distribution of values, etc.). That will tell you if the performance is good enough for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

The Optimizer is not terribly smart when it comes to `LIMIT`.  That spills into the `EXPLAIN`.  That is, do not trust the `EXPLAIN`.

This *may* provide better info:  `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` (if it is available in your version).

That secondary index *should* be perfect for both queries.  Test it with `SELECTs`, not just `EXPLAINs`.

If you run into trouble, you could force a lazy load:

```
SELECT *        -- or whatever columns you ultimately need
    FROM ( SELECT ... LIMIT 1 ) x   -- as you have now
    JOIN ehd_historical_data
        USING(`exchange`, `symbol`, `date`) -- the Primary key
```

Another way to investigate how a query is being run is with the [*Optimizer Trace*](https://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#optimizer_trace)

Based on "Table is 90M rows / 15 GB. RAM is 64 GB. innodb_buffer_pool_size is 4G", I suggest increasing the buffer_pool to at least 20G *unless* you have other processes chewing up the RAM.  This will help speed up many SQL tasks.